# Xamarin Jar binding for Apache Commons Lang 3

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to add a JAR to my Xamarin project that depends on  apache commons lang 3

```
    `<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>`
```

so I installed this [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.ApacheCommonsLang/)  `Xamarin.Android.ApacheCommonsLang`  but I still get the following error  `Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils;'`

Comment: Do you resolve this issue? I have the same problem

Comment: unfortunately, not - I guess I'll need to create my own binding for commons-lang3

Comment: I tried it but there are a lot of errors. But maybe I did something wrong. I solve my issue by downloading the original GitHub repository and replacing StringUtils methods with my own. Then I created binding and it works fine.